# python selenium unable to select element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select below element in a webpage.

```
.active > b:nth-child(1)
```

This is my code :

```
timbro = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.active > b:nth-child(1)')
hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(timbro)
hover.perform()
```

This is part of the error I'm getting:

> Message: Unable to locate element: 
>   {"method":"css selector","selector":".active > b:nth-child(1)"}"

what I'm trying to do is activate a drop down menu so that I can click on another link.

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<li>
    <a href="#nogo" class="main-link active"><b>Menu iniziale</b></a>
    <ul style="display: block;" class="sub-links">
        <li>
            <a href="#nogo" onclick="Esegui('anagrafica.php')">Anagrafica</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#nogo" onclick="Esegui('logout.php')">Fine sessione</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#nogo" onclick="Esegui('main.php')">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#nogo" onclick="Esegui('timbraWFA.php')">Timbro</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant `HTML Snippet`

Comment: <li><a href="#nogo" class="main-link active"><b>Menu iniziale</b></a><ul style="display: block;" class="sub-links"><li><a href="#nogo" onclick="Esegui('anagrafica.php')">Anagrafica</a></li><li><a href="#nogo" onclick="Esegui('logout.php')">Fine sessione</a></li><li><a href="#nogo" onclick="Esegui('main.php')">Home</a></li><li><a href="#nogo" onclick="Esegui('timbraWFA.php')">Timbro</a></li></ul></li> this is the whole html code

Comment: which element you want to identify.

Comment: I'm trying to hover the mouse to "Menu Iniziale" and then click on the last list item "Timbro"

Comment: did you try putting wait before mouse hover, may be there is the case that element isn't loaded completely in `dom` and you are trying to identify it.

Comment: yes i did but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until presence of element as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5) 

menuIniziale = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Menu iniziale")))

hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(menuIniziale).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Timbro"))))
hover.click().build().perform()
```

**Edited1** :- If unfortunately `LINK_TEXT` does not work try using `XPATH` as below :-

```
menuIniziale = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(.,'Menu iniziale')]")))

hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(menuIniziale).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(.,'Timbro')]"))))
hover.click().build().perform()
```

Or try using `CSS_SELECTOR` as below :-

```
menuIniziale = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.main-link")))

hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(menuIniziale).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.sub-links > li:nth-child(4)"))))
hover.click().build().perform()
```

**Edited2** : If this element is inside an `iframe`, you need to switch that `iframe` before finding element as below :-

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(("frame name or id")))

#Now after successfully switching to frame do any one of the above steps
```

**Edited3** :- If you are now able to open menu but not able to select subMenu try as below :-

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(("frame name or id")))

menuIniziale = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.main-link")))

hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(menuIniziale)
hover.build().perform()

subMenu = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(.,'Timbro')]")))
subMenu.click()
```

**Edited4**: Final code

```
menuIniziale = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(.,'Menu iniziale')]")))
hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(menuIniziale)
hover.perform()

subMenu = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(.,'Timbro')]")))
subMenu.click()
hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(subMenu)
hover.click().perform()
```

Comment: i'm getting this error when i try to run this code. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\wfa.py", line 24, in <module>
    menuIniziale = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Menu iniziale")))
  File "C:\Users\alb000096\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: i'm sorry for the mess.

Comment: @ErjolBane once try using `xpath` or `cssSelector` and let me know.. see updated answer...:)

Comment: none of the methods seem to be working. i still get a similar error.

Comment: @ErjolBane did you look for frame or iframe?? make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe...

Comment: i think it is inside an iframe cause the specific element is found on another php file. is there a way to get around this? thanks for your support.

Comment: @ErjolBane Ok then I have edited the answer, you need to switch that frame first then use any one the above code, try with edited answer and let me know..

Comment: i was able to activate the drop down menu but it fails at clicking the "timbro" list item. here is the error.   "Message: Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (29.5, 16.5):"

Comment: @ErjolBane Ok then try third edited answer and let me know..:)

Comment: thanks alot for your help. i managed to make it work with a small tweak.